# Как я могу передать из разных частей кода данные методу?

Tags: c#, wpf

Подскажите, пожалуйста в следующем. Есть вот такой код:

```
/*Код нерабочий, он просто отражает проблему */

public void Method1(int a)
{
     a = 100;
     Method3(a); // вот тут я хочу передать первый параметр
}

public void Method2(int b)
{
     int b = 20; // вот тут я хочу передать второй параметр
     Method3(b);  
}


public void Method3(int a, int b)
{
     textb1.Text = a.ToString();
     textb2.Text = b.ToString();
}
```

Я его чуть изменил, чтобы передать мысль того, что мне нужно. Как мне передать значение, которые вычисляется в `Method1` в 1 аргумент метода `Method 3 (a)`, и также - значение`Method2` в `Method 3 (b)`?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Непонятно, что нужно, непонятно, что делает этот код, непонятно, что он должен делать. У вас шифры вместо названий методов и переменных, такой код очень сложно читать. Суть задания расскажите.

Comment: @aepot сейчас подредачу, чтобы было более понятно

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял, то вам нужно использовать именованные и необязательные аргументы:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments

В вашем примере это будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
    public void Method1(int a)
    {
        a = 100;
        Method3(a: a); // вот тут я хочу передать первый параметр
    }

    public void Method2(int b)
    {
        b = 20; // вот тут я хочу передать второй параметр
        Method3(b: b);
    }

    public void Method3(int a = 0, int b = 0)
    {
        textb1.Text = a.ToString();
        textb2.Text = b.ToString();
    }
```